# Shrink content in math mode to fit into line

Tags: math-mode, spacing, typography

This must be a duplicate, I'm sure, but I just couldn't find the answer.

I want to tell LaTeX to also shrink math, as opposed to only/mainly text, if doing so would allow more content to fit into one line or avoid typographical runts/widows or such. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is a long line, but I would still like to have it fit on one line. $A\in B = C \subseteq D$.
\end{document}
```

yields this unfortunate creation:

[image: scr1]

Meanwhile,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is a long line, but I would still like to have it fit on one line. $A\!\in\!B\!=\!C\!\subseteq\!D$.
\end{document}
```

yields what, in most contexts, might be considered a typographical abomination, but for my purposes (typesetting a cheatsheet) would be preferred:

[image: scr2]

I realize there are answers that talk about allowing LaTeX to reduce interword spacing more, and that [`microtype`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) can also help with such issues, but what I could not find is how to tell LaTeX that reducing horizontal spacing in math mode is also okay.

TL;DR: How can I tell LaTeX to feel free to viciously shrink text *and* math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Math spaces stretch and shrink just as inter word spaces do, but not enough for you here, adding a `minus` component produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\thinmuskip=3mu
%\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
%\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu 

\thinmuskip=3mu  minus 1mu
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu minus 2mu

\begin{document}
\noindent This is a long line, but I would still like to have it fit on one line. $A\in B=C\subseteq D$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: I do this sometimes as well, but I keep these redefinitions local to the one formula where it is needed.